# How to install Basemap in jupyter notebook

Tags: matplotlib-basemap

I am using python 3.6 on my ubuntu 64 bit machine.I have also installed anaconda 4.4.0.How to install basemap in anaconda via jupyter notebook?

Comment: You don't install basemap through jupyter, open up the anaconda prompt and type in `pip install basemap`

Answer (score 4):

You can directly install it using Anaconda Navigator.Please follow the below steps:

1. Open "Anaconda Navigator"
2. Go to "Environments"
3. On the Environments Page, select **Not Installed** from the drop down menu.
4. Search **basemap** (or any package you want to install)
5. Select and click Apply

I hope it will help.
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't post answers that consist largely of references to external sites. In this case, you could have cropped the image and included it in-line, within your post.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I am new here so didn't know this etiquette. I have modified my answer as per the guidance.

Answer (score 0):

@Ken is right, you don't install on Jupyter. You might like to follow the install guide at https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap#install.

This requires downloading numpy and matplotlib beforehand, which can be easily done by running `pip install numpy matplotlib` on the command line interface.

Once done, you can put the code up on Jupyter. The example below is taken from http://basemaptutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plotting_data.html.

```py
map = Basemap(projection='ortho', lat_0=0, lon_0=0)

map.drawmapboundary(fill_color='aqua') 
map.fillcontinents(color='coral', lake_color='aqua') 
map.drawcoastlines()

x, y = map(0, 0)

map.plot(x, y, marker='D',color='m')

plt.show()
```

[image]

I just installed it and this works well for me.

Answer (score -1):

The following 3 steps solved my problem:

```
    conda config --add channels conda-forge
    conda config --set channel_priority strict
    conda install basemap
```